# Fibonacci loop that keeps on asking

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, fibonacci

This is my code that tells incrementing Fibonacci number you asked and stops when you insert "-1", everything works well.I need it to tell me same number all the time but here if i insert for ex. 12 it says:89, which is correct. But the second time i do it it gives me 10946 and so on, always increases. Ideas how to fix this and let the 89 or else number stay the same?

```
int first= 0;
int second= 1;
int next= 0;
Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("tell the fibonacci number you want to know:");
 while(true){
int fib= scanner.nextInt();// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21

if(fib== -1){  System.out.println("program ends");break;}
else if(fib== 2)System.out.println("1");
else{ 
  if(fib==0){System.out.println("error, tell fibonacci one more time: "); 
    continue; //This will jump to the next loop of while, asking the number fib.  Not really necessary with the if else construct done here.
}
else{        
    for(int count= 3; count<=fib;count++){
    next= first+second;            
    first= second;
    second=next;}            
System.out.println(next);
}
```

Comment: What do you think `while (true)` does?  Under what conditions do you think this loop will exit?

Comment: On a related note, you say you "got error/unexpected loops" when trying to implement your looping logic.  What error might that be?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first= 0;
    int second= 1;
    int next= 0;
    Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("tell the fibonacci number you want to know:");
     while(true)   //<<--- Here. You will execute the next line forever.
    int fib= scanner.nextInt();// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21

    if(fib== -1){  System.out.println("program ends");}
    else if(fib== 2)System.out.println("1");     
    else { 
        while(fib==0){
            System.out.println("error, tell fibonacci one more time: "); 
            fib = scanner.nextInt();
        }        
        for(int count= 3; count<=fib;count++){
            next= first+second;            
            first= second;
            second=next;
        }            
    System.out.println(next);        
}
```

Correct way to use while(true):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first= 0;
    int second= 1;
    int next= 0;
    Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("tell the fibonacci number you want to know:");
    while(true){
        int fib= scanner.nextInt();// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21

        if(fib== -1){ System.out.println("program ends");}
        else if(fib== 2) System.out.println("1");
        else { 
            if(fib==0){
                System.out.println("error, tell fibonacci one more time: "); 
                continue; //This will jump to the next loop of while, asking the number fib.  Not really necessary with the if else construct done here. Also, you can use a switch-case to check the value of fib.
            } else {        
                for(int count= 3; count<=fib;count++){
                    next= first+second;            
                    first= second;
                    second=next;
                 }            
                 System.out.println(next);
            }
      }        
}
```

Comment: When i want for example fib number 12, it says 89 which is correct. But when i ask for it second time it says 10946. How can I get 89 all the time?

Comment: Easy, set the first and second variables to the initial values INSIDE the while loop. When this kind of thing happens, you should run a loop in your mind, and see what happens to variables. If you check the for loop, the next value is overwritten without reading it, but first and second have the values from previous while loops.

Answer (score 1):

Put your Scanner inside the loop.

```
    while(true){
     Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
     int fib= scanner.nextInt();// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
     if(fib == -1) break;
    ....
    }
```

Comment: How will creating a new scanner each time help anything?

Comment: @Stan It evaluates only one number. If you want to add multiple numbers you have to work with arrays.